# How to write a formula searching for specific text in a cell range and offsetting the value

Tags: microsoft-excel

My Excel sheet has 2 tabs, the first tab (called Date) has a column with text I am searching for and a date in the 2nd column.

[image: First Tab]

Within my second tab (called Information) , I would like to search the first tab for text in column 1. I have written the following code:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Move In (IN) 1", Date!A1:A2)), OFFSET(Date!A1:A2, 0, 1), "")
```

I wrote the above formula in cell B2 (tab Information). This works as intended.

[image: Second Tab]

When I use the same formula in cell B4, the text shows in the cell below it. When I used the formula in cell B7, the text displays 2 cells below it.

How can I use this formula multiple times but have the text display in the formula cell where it is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed my formula to use a VLOOKUP.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Move In (IN) 1", Date!A:B, 2, 0), "")
```

Comment: Does that work?  If so, you are allowed to tick your own answer in 24hrs.

Comment: Yes, the answer does work.